# Is it possible to get container type in AutoFac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

For example, I have registered class C1 with one parameter in constructor of type `System.Type`. I have another class (C2) with injected parameter of type C1. And I want receive `typeof(C2)` automatically in C1 constructor. Is it possible in some way?

Example code:

```
public class C1
{
  public C1(Type type) {}

  // ...
}

public class C2
{
  public C2(C1 c1) {}

  // ...
}

// Registration
containerBuilder.Register(???);
containerBuilder.Register<C2>();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it:

```
builder.RegisterType<C1>();
builder.RegisterType<C2>();
builder.RegisterModule(new ExposeRequestorTypeModule());
```

Where:

```
class ExposeRequestorTypeModule : Autofac.Module
{
    Parameter _exposeRequestorTypeParameter = new ResolvedParameter(
       (pi, c) => c.IsRegistered(pi.ParameterType),
       (pi, c) => c.Resolve(
           pi.ParameterType,
           TypedParameter.From(pi.Member.DeclaringType)));

    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
            IComponentRegistry registry,
            IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing += (s, e) => {
            e.Parameters = new[] { _exposeRequestorTypeParameter }
                .Concat(e.Parameters);
        };
    }
}
```

Any component that takes a `System.Type` parameter will get the type of the requestor passed to it (if any.) A possible improvement might be to use a `NamedParameter` rather than `TypedParameter` to restrict the `Type` parameters that will be matched to only those with a certain name.

Please let me know if this works, others have asked about the same general task and this would be good to share with them.

Comment: No, unfortunately, it doesn't work. LimitType is type of component itself (C1 in this case)

Comment: Ah - doh! - thanks for that. I'll have a think about alternatives and post them here if I find any.

Comment: Main problem is in AutowiringParameter. It always invokes resolve for children without parameters (with empty enumerable). I created similar parameter and registered it in registration.ActivatorData.ConfiguredParameters (where ActivatorData is ReflectionActivatorData) with value: registration.ActivatorData.ImplementationType. But it works only for explicit c.Resolve<C2> (and with injection of C1 itself I got 'Non of constructors found...' for C1)..

Comment: Hi- I've updated the answer to hopefully fix the problem. Let me know if you can give it a try.

Comment: Yeah, it works (I just changed pi.DeclaringType to pi.Member.DeclaringType). Much thanks.